# Checking if a Stripe Coupon is invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, coupon

I am using the stripe gem for rails and I am trying to check if a user's coupon code is invalid. If the code is invalid, then the user is redirected to `users/show.html.haml`

Here is my code

```
if Stripe::Coupon.retrieve(current_user.coupon_code) == nil
  redirect_to user_path(current_user)
end
```

I thought that retrieving the code from Stripe and checking whether or not the value is `nil` would work but the error message I get is:

```
Stripe::InvalidRequestError in SubscribersController#new
No such coupon: *Whatever the invalid coupon name is (ex. "ASDF")*
```

Any idea as to what is going on here? I looked through the Stripe documentation for Ruby and didn't see any info on how to check if a code is invalid. Is there another way to check if a code is equal or not equal to `nil`?

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/api#errors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the coupon ID you pass to `Stripe::Coupon.retrieve(...)` does not exist, the request will fail and a `Stripe::InvalidRequestError` exception will be raised.

Therefore, instead of comparing the result to `nil`, you need to place the call to `Stripe::Coupon.retrieve(...)` in a begin/rescue/end block to catch the `Stripe::InvalidRequestError` exception.

You can find out more about error handling with Stripe's API here: https://stripe.com/docs/api#errors

Answer (score 2):

For background info see [Ywain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37102066/3437900) and
In ruby,

```
  # @return [Boolean]
  # #
  def is_valid?(coupon)
    return false unless coupon.present?

    coupon_retrieved = Stripe::Coupon.retrieve(coupon)
    coupon_retrieved.valid == true

  rescue => error
    puts "#{error.class} :: #{error.message}"
    false
  end
```